Output files in s3 bucket not getting overwritten on running Dbt - spark model configured with Iceberg table
We have a model in dbt cloud config with spark running on AWS EMR with Iceberg as target table type.
Currently we have set the config: materialized: 'table' and every time the model runs, it creates output files in the s3 bucket without deleting or overwriting the files created in the previous run.
Can someone please how to configure in dbt spark model to delete the output files related to previous execution in s3 bucket on each run?
Expectation: For every model run, output files stored in s3 bucket on previous run should get deleted

With these modern data formats, try not to concern yourself with the files themselves -- they are managed by the engine (eg EMR).
One benefit of formats like Iceberg and Delta is that they keep the underlying data files plus a 'log' that keeps track of changes. You then have the ability to "go back in time" to a previous state of the table. This is made possible by the fact that it keeps all historical data.
If you do not wish to keep the historical data (which means you won't be able to time-travel), you can configure the table to expire snapshots.
From Maintenance - Apache Iceberg:

Each write to an Iceberg table creates a new snapshot, or version, of a table. Snapshots can be used for time-travel queries, or the table can be rolled back to any valid snapshot.
Snapshots accumulate until they are expired by the expireSnapshots operation. Regularly expiring snapshots is recommended to delete data files that are no longer needed, and to keep the size of table metadata small.


Thanks for the input John. This gives clarity about the new table format. To delete/expire both data and metadata, where we need to set the config?  Is it at EMR or DBT CLOUD. And what's the config we need to use?

Judging from the documentation, it's a command to run in Spark that will set a configuration on the table in EMR. This looks like it would be helpful: Apache Iceberg optimization: Solving the small files problem in Amazon EMR | AWS Big Data Blog
